# How do I find seconds since midnight?

Tags: date

Using the `date` program, how can I calculate the number of seconds since midnight?

Comment: date "+(%H*60+%M)*60+%S" | bc

Comment: echo $(($(date '+(%H*60+%M)*60+%S')))

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To avoid race conditions, still assuming GNU date:

```bash
eval "$(date +'today=%F now=%s')"
midnight=$(date -d "$today 0" +%s)
echo "$((now - midnight))"
```

With `zsh`, you can do it internally:

```bash
zmodload zsh/datetime
now=$EPOCHSECONDS
strftime -s today %F $now
strftime -rs midnight %F $today
echo $((now - midnight))
```

Portably, in timezones where there's no daylight saving switch, you could do:

```bash
eval "$(date +'h=%H m=%M s=%S')"
echo "$((${h#0} * 3600 + ${m#0} * 60 
+ ${s#0}))"
```

The `${X#0}` is to strip one leading 0 which in some shells like `bash`, `dash` and `posh` cause problems with `08` and `09` (where the shell complains about it being an invalid octal number).

Comment: Very clever and good use of eval

Comment: I'd rather use something along these lines: `IFS=: read -r today now <<< $(date +%F:%s); midnight=$(date -d "$today 0" +%s); echo $(( now - midnight ))`

Answer (score 15):

There is no need for any arithmetic expression, just use pure date:

```
date -d "1970-01-01 UTC $(date +%T)" +%s
```

Comment: Great answer, should be the top one.

Comment: On Mac `brew install coreutils` and replace `date` with `gdate`

Comment: In timezones with daylight saving time, that gives incorrect results 2 days per year. For instance, in the UK at 2am on 2020-10-25 (the last Sunday in October), which is 3 hours after midnight as there have been a time change at 1am earlier, it gives 7200 instead of 10800.

Comment: Actually, arithmetic expressions can be much faster than shelling out to external command twice. There are other ways to do the job, with calling `date` only once.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [bash, get current time in milliseconds since midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16169701/1983854), on a GNU system, it can be done like this:

```
$ now=$(date '+%s')
$ midnight=$(date -d 'today 00:00:00' '+%s')
$ echo $(( now - midnight ))
53983
```

Comment: You want to make sure you don't do that at 23:59:59

Comment: And to convert back: `date -d @$seconds`

Comment: There's a race if the day changes between the two `date` commands.

Answer (score 1):

**Seconds since midnight?**

For Bash (with GNU `date`) here are two one-liners which work equally well:

```
echo $(( - $(date -d 0 +%s) + EPOCHSECONDS ))
```

or

```
echo $(( $(date '+%-H *3600 + %-M *60 + %-S') ))
```

Either one works just as well.

Similarly, I find it useful to have a function for minutes since midnight:

```
minutes () { echo $(( $(date '+%-H *60 + %-M') )) ;}
```