# How to determine & convert current time to no of seconds elapsed during current day?

Tags: date, timestamps

I want to ask your that how to determine & convert current time to no of seconds elapsed during current day?

Actually, I want to show how long is midnight from now in seconds. As total seconds in a day is 86400 so I'll subtract current time (in seconds elapsed since this day) with 86400.

EDIT:

Here is the actual question. If `date -d` is not working then how can our instructor give question like this. There might be a way maybe. Anyone understand this question. They have a different way that is subract from no of seconds.

[image]

Comment: Related: [How do I find seconds since midnight?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146550/how-do-i-find-seconds-since-midnight)

Comment: Hey @steeldriver can you tell me is there any other way than `-d` parameter in date command to calculate no of seconds until midnight. Solution below is great, but -d is ot working. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with other implementations of the `date` command - for a more platform-independent solution you might want to look at languages that provide their own datetime functions, such as `perl`

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks can you please help me. I have posted the actual question PIC also. There might be a way or a hint in the question if `date -d` doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Well, you can trivially get the elapsed seconds since 00:00:00 today using `date` with respectively `+%H`, `+%M`, `+%S` and basic arithmetic (in the syntax appropriate for the shell of your instructor's choice). Then - assuming you aren't expected to account for the possibility of leap seconds occurring before tomorrow - simple subtraction will give you the number of seconds remaining until *next* 00:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
eval "`date +'@ s = (86400 - %S) - 60 * (%M + 60 * %H)'`"; echo $s
```

However note that in timezones that have winter and summer time, it won't give  the right result if called on the day of the switch from/to summer time, before the switch (which generally happen very early in the morning).

Beware that in `csh`, arithmetic operators are [right-associative](//stackoverflow.com/questions/930486/what-is-associativity-of-operators-and-why-is-it-important) with `*/` having precedence over `+-`, as in

```
@ s = 1 - 2 + 3 - 4
```

is

```
@ s = 1 - (2 + (3 - 4))
```

And not:

```
@ s = (((1 - 2) + 3) - 4)
```

as in other languages. That was fixed in `tcsh` (6.15.01), and you can run `set compat_expr` to get back to the older behaviour there.

Hence the parentheses around `86400 - %S` so it works in both `csh` and `tcsh`.

Comment: yo man! it worked :D :D :D Thanks man. The other solution were great, but this one worked for me so I changed my accept answer and also they got their upvotes so I hope they won't mind. But I didn't get what you said about timezones. I live in Vancouver, British Columbia, Canada with Pacific Standard Time.

Comment: @Tony, in Vancouver, 2016-11-06 is a 25 hour long day for instance. At 02:00, the clock goes back to 01:00 again to switch to winter time which adds an extra hour. If you run that command at 00:30 before the switch, that's 24.5 hours before midnight, but that command will report 23.5 hours because it calculates 24 hours take away the current time.

Comment: At that time our course would have been finished :D, but thanks a lot for this information.

Comment: Dear Stephane, could you please help me in this question? You are a genius. Hope you don't mind.  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296372/how-to-determine-current-users-who-are-logged-in-using-a-specific-domain-unix

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have GNU date (or another `date` program that understands `-d` and works properly) and using `bash`:

You can use the `-d` flag to report time at various points.  So, for example

```
% date -d "00:00:00 tomorrow"
Sat Jul 16 00:00:00 EDT 2016
```

We can use this to report on seconds with `+%s`

```
% date -d "00:00:00 tomorrow" +%s
1468641600
```

We know our current time, in seconds:

```
% date +%s                       
1468633682
```

So we can calculate the difference:

```
% secs_left=$(( $(date -d "00:00:00 tomorrow" +%s) - $(date +%s) ))
% echo $secs_left
7871
```

(Which is about right; 7871 seconds is 2hrs 11mins and 11 seconds, which is correct for when I ran that command).

EDIT for `csh` as requested:

In `csh` the similar command would be

```
% @ secs_left = ( `date -d "00:00:00 tomorrow" +%s` - `date +%s` )
% echo $secs_left
7871
```

Comment: Hey bro, really sorry to tell you I am bound to use Csh. Can you please tell in that. Thanks

Comment: `csh` commands added, but I really don't recommend you write code in `csh` - see https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html for reasons.  Long term you'll be grateful to learn `bash` syntax!

Comment: Yes! I agree. it was our instructor's choice. And is there any other way than -d parameter? In Gator date works date -u also works but not date -d. Thanks

Comment: Although it didn't helped me much as I'm still stucked in `date -d` error , but your asnwer is definitely great. So, you deserve accept asnwer. Thanks . If possilbe kindly help

Comment: Your instructor is expecting you to call `date` with `+%H` to get the current hours, with `%+M` to get current minutes and `%+S` to get seconds.  From there you can calculate (similar to the `@` line in my answer) the number of seconds from midnight.    At this point you have all the information you need to do the calculation.

Comment: you are using `'+%s'` but that is not allowed, only `'+%S'`

Answer (score 1):

in csh it is pretty simple:

```
    set start_time = `date +%s`
    set end_time = `date +%s`
    @ time_elapsed = $end_time - $start_time
    echo "$time_elapsed time elapsed in seconds"
    @ time_elapsed = `date -u -r $time_elapsed +%T`
    echo = "$time_elapsed time elapsed in hh:mm:ss format"
```

Answer (score 0):

this reads like a homework question.

given that you are constrained to only getting hours minutes and seconds  you will have to take those numbers and do arithmentic. the arithmetic is not complex, I'm sure you can work it out.

**this will not give a reliable result** because there is a **race condition** if the minute changes during the determination of those three input values so steps should be taken to detect this fault and correct for it.

use the result form @StevenHaris' answer to confirm your calculations are correct,

Comment: One can always use `eval \`date '+h=%H m=%M s=%S'\`` to get all three values at once.