# How to determine current users who are logged in using a specific domain? | UNIX

Tags: shell, grep, users, csh, domain

I want to know How to determine current users who are logged in using a specific domain?

For example, here is the question. Please tell according to it using the grep command and use of wc.

> **Question:** Write a C shell script called `countkpu` which determines how many of the currently logged in users are logged in from a computer on the kwantlen.ca domain.
>
> To do this, note the `who` command will show each user who is logged in along with identification of their computer.
>
> You can feed this information to the `grep` command, to only display strings that contain the "kwantlen.ca". You can then further feed this output to the `wc` command, which can be used in such a way to just count lines of output.

HERE IS WHAT I DID:

```
grep `hostname` /etc/hosts
```

results:

```
10.65.36.35    gator    gator.kwantlen.ca   loghost
```

The Problem is how will I combine the `who` command as in the question? I mean it is not telling who is logged in using this domain.

Comment: Please edit your question rather than reposting it. And don't use new accounts to bypass question rate limits, using multiple accounts to evade system restrictions is not allowed.

Comment: @Gilles What do you want me to edit it now? I think by posting the question (IN TEXT)  I can best explain you. Hope you understand and I respect StackExchange policy. Can you please help me?

Comment: @Fred:  I'm sure if you paid a little bit more attention to your course, you could get it done in 10 minutes.  If you show us a good effort in solving it yourself, we could certainly help you.

Comment: @JuliePelletier thanks. I have written what I did. Please can you help me?

Comment: Keep going...  You could use `cut` to extract the IP address from the `who` lines.

Comment: @JuliePelletier don't mind, but after this, I don't have any clue what to do. Please help me if you know what to do

Comment: /etc/hosts is probably a dead end.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Ok So, would you like to help me? I posted the question also.

Comment: Fred or Tony, the homework question spells out the commands to run, even in the order you'd type them. Have you learned about pipes in this class?

Comment: Why are people still teaching C-shell?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I know that, but this one looks complicated. If you know, would you like to share your knowledge with us?

Comment: @glennjackman - `csh` is unfortunately still popular in academic/scientific computing.  It's what the professors learnt in the 80s and their students are going to have to suffer it too if they want to pass.

Comment: Somebody should show them [this](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/ "Csh Programming Considered Harmful") (also posted [here](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot "Csh Programming Considered Harmful")).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question nearly gives it away, if you're familiar with [pipes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30759/whats-a-good-example-of-piping-commands-together):

> To do this, note the `who` command will show each user who is logged in along with identification of their computer.
>
> You can feed this information to the `grep` command, to only display strings that contain the "kwantlen.ca". You can then further feed this output to the `wc` command, which can be used in such a way to just count lines of output.

The answer they're probably looking for, in a form usable by either csh or bash or zsh or ksh:

```
who | grep kwantlen.ca | wc -l
```

or, to golf it shorter:

```
who | grep -c kwantlen.ca
```

References:

- [man page for wc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wc)
- [man page for grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)

Comment: Yes first I did like this, but here is my confusion, you know when we give a command `who` it display all the users using the UNIX. In my case, I can see the users but there is not text like "kwantlen.ca" ; I can see their IP address , usernames, but where is kwantlen.ca ? It never displays!!  so ultimately your command also does the same thing like what I did before posting this question that is nothing gets appeared. What do you think if kwantlen.ca never gets appeared in `who` command then what is our instructor mean?

Comment: Apparently they are logged in from somewhere else! 0 might be the right answer in that case. Or maybe the IPs aren't getting resolved to names.

Comment: yes I think IP address aren't resolved to names, you know how ? let's suppose I'm at home I know my IP address will be assigned by my internet service provider and its for example telus.net, but the person I can see right now he is in Kwantlen Polytechnic University and using the gator from there, but his IP address is also some numbers eg. 452. 234. 234. 454  instead of @kwantlen.net at the end which should be because he is in University. Do you have a solution for resolving to names ?

Comment: I don't. I suspect you have the answer the teacher wants.

Comment: Yup! I think so this would be an answer and teacher is just trying to trick us and it wasted so much my time. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: it's not necessarily a trick question. speaking from my experience working at universities, some departments/schools/faculties do the right thing when it comes to reverse-DNS for their hostnames.  Others don't.  Worst of all are central IT depts who always seem to decide that it's all too much trouble and don't bother. `who | grep -c kwantlen.ca` answers the question as asked.  If you want to go beyond that, find a list of your uni's IP address blocks and grep for IPs matching them too.  [grepcidr](http://www.pc-tools.net/unix/grepcidr/) is a good tool for that.